# Get TrueType font glyphs for current Windows locale in Multi-Byte Character Set

Tags: c++, windows, fonts, mfc, truetype

I want to create text renderer in OpenGL. For this I need to have font glyphs rendered into a texture. I've used `FreeType` lib to create glyphs with `SDF` (singed distance fields). The problem is, when I'm trying create glyphs for (unsigned) chars in range 0-255, the chars above 127 are different than what I'm getting from MFC using `TextOut`.
I've found that MFC is somehow changing chars above 127 to another characters depending on currently Windows language.
For example I have a Polish letter `ą`: its -71 for char, 185 in unsigned char, and 261 in Multi-Byte chars set.
`FreeType` lib is able to create Multi-Byte chars, so when I force it to render a texture for `261`, I'm getting a correct texture.

The question is how can I map char values to Multi-Byte wchars in current Windows language? I want to get the same characters rendered by `FreeType` lib as I'm getting by rendering unsigned chars in range 0-255 by MFC `TextOut`.

I've tried to get that info using combination of `GetFontLanguageInfo` and `GetCharacterPlacement`, but cannot make it work as intended.
I've tried also to create `std:string` with all char (-127 to 127) and then convert it to `std::wstring` using `std::wstring_convert`, but this also not worked as intended. Also I had some problems with setting correct `Codecvt`, so maybe fault was in this option.

Changing project settings to use Multi-Byte chars set is not possibile.

Comment: *"The question is how can I map char values to Multi-Byte wchars"* - That's an odd question. Simply don't use any sort of ANSI/codepage encoding, and this issue won't even come up. I wonder why you're avoiding Unicode.

Comment: @IInspectable because I have very large and old code base, so changing to Unicode will take a lot of time, so it will be hard to convince the company to make it :)
Somehow MFC `TextOut` is doing it correctly, so I wanted to know how they are doing it, or even use some functions provided by them to convert that depending on current Windows language.

Comment: There is no `TextOut` in MFC. That's a Win32 API call. As for *"changing to Unicode"*, there's no reason to somehow change your project configuration. Just use the Unicode API version where you want to (such as here) and leave everything else as is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got a solution!

```
    //create array of all chars from 0to 255
    std::array<unsigned char, 255> charsArray;
    std::iota(std::begin(charsArray), std::end(charsArray), 0);

    //create WCHAR array for converted string
    std::array<WCHAR, 255> wcharsArray;
    std::fill(std::begin(wcharsArray), std::end(wcharsArray), 0);

    //convert chars array to wchar array using `system default Windows ANSI code page` (CP_ACP)
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, charsArray.data(), 255, wcharsArray.data(), 255);

    for (unsigned char c = 0; c < 255; c++)
    {
        //when loading glyphs from the FreeType lib i just have to call wcharsArray[c] to generate correct glyphs
        FT_Load_Char(face, wcharsArray[c], FT_LOAD_RENDER);
        //... some stuff with adding glyphs to the textures
    }
```

Comment: Again, doesn't make sense. Why are you using ANSI/codepage encoding when you don't need to? Construct the 255 Unicode code points and go from there. This isn't the '90s anymore.

Comment: how? can you tell me little more about it? or share example code?